# Eliminating or removing halos in Aurora HDR

Tags: hdr, halos

I'm looking to eliminate or remove halos in Aurora HDR. I have seen many tutorials on how to do this in Lightroom, Photoshop and Photomatix but nothing for Aurora HDR Pro or Aurora HDR 2017.

When I use "Ghosts Reduction" prior to importing 3 raw images, the halos appear in the imported image. Once the image is loaded, I would like to remove the halos if possible. Mostly they show up in the sky and trees.

The attached photo shows what the halos look like.

Thanks.

[image: This images shows halos in the sky between the trees]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uncheck the Ghosts Reduction option and check Alignment instead. In this photo, alignment will do a good job handling moving objects and there will be no effects in the image.